# empty notepad file instead of the one written on in c#

Tags: c#, file-io, streamwriter, notepad

When I call this function it just opens several empty notepad windows but if I open the `text2` file after run, it shows me all the entered lines... I even tried flush to write all that is in the buffer but no help.

```
static void finish()
{
    FileStream fs2 = new FileStream("C:\\Users\\ayush.mishra\\Desktop\\text2.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    using(StreamWriter s = new StreamWriter(fs2))
    {
        s.WriteLine("This Notepad will self destruct in....");
        fs2.Flush();
        Process notepadProcess2 = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\ayush.mishra\\Desktop\\text2.txt");
        for (var i = 0; i < 40000000.00; i++);
        notepadProcess2.CloseMainWindow();
        s.WriteLine(" ******  5  ****** ");
        fs2.Flush();
        notepadProcess2 = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\ayush.mishra\\Desktop\\text2.txt");
        for (var i = 0; i < 400000000; i++);
        notepadProcess2.CloseMainWindow();
        s.WriteLine(" ******  4  ****** ");
        fs2.Flush();
        notepadProcess2 = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\ayush.mishra\\Desktop\\text2.txt");
        for (var i = 0; i < 400000000; i++);
        notepadProcess2.CloseMainWindow();
        s.WriteLine(" ******  3  ****** ");
        fs2.Flush();
        notepadProcess2 = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\ayush.mishra\\Desktop\\text2.txt");
        for (var i = 0; i < 400000000; i++);
        notepadProcess2.CloseMainWindow();
        notepadProcess2 = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\ayush.mishra\\Desktop\\text2.txt");
        s.WriteLine(" ******  2  ****** ");
        fs2.Flush();
        for (var i = 0; i < 400000000; i++);
        notepadProcess2.CloseMainWindow();
        notepadProcess2 = Process.Start("C:\\Users\\ayush.mishra\\Desktop\\text2.txt");
        s.WriteLine(" ******  1  ****** ");
        fs2.Flush();
        for (var i = 0; i < 400000000; i++);
        notepadProcess2.CloseMainWindow();
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The file is locked, in such case Notepad probably just show empty file instead of error message.

Comment: Instead of iterating through a loop, you may want to use a `Thread.Sleep()` or a `Timer` for timing purposes. Even if incrementing an int 400 million times takes 1 second, in 10 years it'll be over in a flash on modern PCs with faster CPUs. Some of the oldest video games have become unplayably fast on modern PCs, for similar reasons.

Comment: Close the FileStream instead of Flushing it. Or try to call a constructor with [FileSharing option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx), but since you are creating new file it may be not helpful.

Comment: @ShadowWizard i made i have another text file opened simultaneously through a thread which shows the data that did not have any problem with the lock..

Comment: @Artemix how will closing the file really help..  cos i was avoiding trying that cos it seems too cumbersome...

Comment: The lock is per file, other text file is not relevant.

Comment: @Pundit When you close the file the locks are released and other applications can see the file contents. When you just Flush the locks are still kept and only current process can read the file contents.

Comment: @Atemix i think i understand...  but i am closing the notepad file before writing to it..  in this case will the problem still persist and if it does can you suggest a way to fulfill the intention...

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are opening the file first in notepad and then writing data to it. Since file is already opened in notepad so it will not show changes. But if you open file again in notepad it will display data written to it.

Comment: the already opened file is supposed to show written part before it..  thats why i close it each time but still it appears empty each time...

Comment: so notepad closes when you call notepadProcess2.CloseMainWindow()?

Comment: yes.  it terminates the process..  thus closing the notepad file..  you can run this method in a main class to check the output..

Comment: Data is being written to the file when using statement is ended. So that's why you are just seeing notepad file opening again and again without any text.

Comment: that will be because file is opened in notepad, or notepad will be displaying a save dialog. Why you don't use File.WriteAllLines(string []) method?

Comment: well the intention here is to show the countdown as it happens...  and if you would run it you would see that the notepad files get closed before opening it again without a problem...  so maybe that is not the problem..